# Parse Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript

I'm loading a JavaScript from an external URL:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
if (HasFlash()) {
    EmbedViewerSwf(
        "/static/flash/CBV_2p645.swf",
        'mia7777',
        'edge33-b.stream.highwebmedia.com',
        '/xml/viewer.xml',
        '0',
        'login_required_true_if_loggedin',
         '0' ,
        "https://ssl-ccstatic.highwebmedia.com/flash/playerProductInstall.swf",
        'mario4025',
        "$.mydefchatconn('join_group_show')",
        "$.mydefchatconn('spy_on_private')",
        'registration_required()',
        '0',
        "https://ssl-ccstatic.highwebmedia.com/images/flashwatermark.png",
        "chaturbate.com",
        'pbkdf2_sha256%2412000%242NlTeIelZxcU%24j9/x/yjBjRqHJkntlLjDUkBJkh1dEC7XR8sh78/4T2w%3D',
        'd2278438db4d37ad094a07e221b30c89ff07627cd1b1732d2f298328a71e9985',
        '100',
        '100'
    );
}
else {
    var html = "<div id='still_video' style='display: none'>";
    html += "<video id='still_video_object'";
    html += "src='http://origin13.stream.highwebmedia.com:1935/live-origin/mia7777-sd-5fd38820138291f9bcf6baa6ac062829f12567166a09f34d50fd93de58a65c79_aac/playlist.m3u8'";
    html += "width='498px' height='407px'";
    html += "webkit-playsinline autoplay></video></div>";
    $('#still_video_container').html(html);
    $('#still_video').show();
}




    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    if (!($.cookie('supress_bline')) && userAgent.indexOf('bline') == -1  && (userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') >= 0 || userAgent.indexOf('iPod') >= 0)) {
        $('#bline_notice').show();
    }
    $('#dismiss_bline_notice').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#bline_notice').hide();
        $.cookie('supress_bline', 1, { expires: 30, path: '/' });
    });
});
}
```

How can I get the contents of the `html` variable declared in the code above (using PHP or JavaScript):

```
 html += "src='http://origin13.stream.highwebmedia.com:1935/live-origin/mia7777-sd-5fd38820138291f9bcf6baa6ac062829f12567166a09f34d50fd93de58a65c79_aac/playlist.m3u8'";
```

I tried it with `document.getElementById` and also by parsing the whole HTML on my site and then using `document.writeln` and getting out the variable, but I'm stuck on this part.

Comment: I spent 5 full minutes parsing your question and I still have no idea what you're asking for...

Comment: the above code posted is on another site (url). i need to get this variable from this site and parse it to my site. so im having an outpout of "src='http://origin13.stream.highwebmedia.com:1935/live-origin/mia7777-sd-5fd38820138291f9bcf6baa6ac062829f12567166a09f34d50fd93de58a65c79_aac/playlist.m3u8'" .. i know its difficult to explain..

Comment: its an open source streaming website, so just fetching the url is not a crime ;)

Comment: then what is google doing, fechting and indexing all sites ;) it is also not a nice way ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only with Javascript, you may find cross site scripting issues.

If you really need to parse it, and have permission to do so, you should be doing it server-side, with something like PHP or ASP.NET.

As the actual method to parse it, it might be done using regex (since you know the string starts with `"src='` and ends with `'";`

Comment: hey, do you know how the regex string look like for getting the outpout. have been searching all over the net but cant find a solution..

Comment: The regex would be `html \+= "src='(.*)'";`. This should be enough to get the line you want, with the URL in a matching group.